# ¿Cómo almacenar resultados de modelo predictivo Python, en SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql

Buen día

tengo un modelo el predictivo que al terminar me genera un Excel y si falla un cvs hasta hay todo bien pero ahora necesito que aparte de generar el Excel me lo guarde también en SQL server de esto ya tengo la conexión lista lo que no se es como guardar mis datos en la tabla

adjunto la parte del código donde genera los datos

gracias de antemano

```
 # Generar XLS/CSVfinal y almacenar en Sql 
exclude_cols = ['score','sheetname']
if len(deliver.index) < 65000:
    deliver.drop(columns=exclude_cols).to_excel((filename.split('.')[0] + '_pred.xlsx'),engine='xlsxwriter',index=False)
else:
    # temp solutiond
    deliver.drop(columns=exclude_cols).to_csv((filename.split('.')[0] + '_pred.csv'),index=False)
```

Librerías usadas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import warnings
import pickle
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Estas usando pandas?

Comment: si señor edite la pregunta para que se puedan ver las librerias

Comment: entonces puedes usar `.to_sql()`

Comment: podrías indicarme como consultado intente esto  --- deliver.to_sql(nombre de la tabla.con=nombre de variable que guarda conexion )------  pero me sale un errror que el nombre de la tabla  me aparece undefined

Comment: deberías editar tu pregunta para así poder entender mejor tu problema